# buliding Vue SPA authentication with Laravel Sanctum and Fortify

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-page-application, fortify, laravel-sanctum

When sending POST request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`, `CSRF` protection for the application will be initialized, During this request, `Laravel` will set an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie containing the current `CSRF` token. This token should then be passed in an `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header on subsequent requests, I was thinking, if i go to `devtools > storage > cookies`, then i can grab that `csrf` cookie and then use it manually and gain access to the application without logging in, if so, then how is that any secure ? shouldn't `SPA` authentication also has a method to destroy or revoke this cookie, shouldn't doing `POST` request to `fortify` route `/logout` destroy or revoke the cookie and then generate new one on future logins? if no then what is even the point of logging out ?, also shouldn't `fortify` and `sanctum` provide a way to revoke the cookie in case of `SPA` authentication like they do in `API Token Authentication` and `Mobile Application Authentication` ?